# How to send task name instead of alert id in kapacitor?

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor, chronograf

when an alert triggered in kapacitor, it sends alert id (name of the alert that's defined in chronograf UI), but I need its task name that's generated automatically.

I'm trying to find out which CLEAR event belongs to which CRITICAL event.
In this image, id field is alert name not alet's auto generated id.

this is debug screenshot 
[image: this is debug screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use chronograf UI, it generates own TICK script for kapacitor. So it defines alert name as alert id into the frontend. I solved my problem with [kapacitor APIs](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/working/api).